# What are the specific requirements of the first partition for MLO to boot?

Tags: bootloader, u-boot

I have tried a couple different commands to format the first partition and both result in MLO not booting.

```
# Attempt 1
mkfs.vfat -F 32 -s 8 /dev/mmcblk0p1

# Attempt 2
mkfs.vfat -F 32 -S 4096 /dev/mmcblk0p1
```

The thing I don't understand and what I am looking for more information on is why the following way *does* appear to work.

```
mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/mmcblk0p1
```

So, it appears there is some special requirement regarding the sector sizing of the first partition in order for MLO to boot properly. Do you know what those requirements are? I have tried searching the U-boot documentation without success and am waiting on replies on IRC. If I find anything I will update this post.

Comment: you need to set the boot flag, for that partition.

Comment: I can confirm that I have set the boot flag. The `mkfs.vfat` command doesn't affect that.

Comment: you need to set the geometry and sectors follow this link http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/SD/MMC_format_for_OMAP3_boot